# UIVisualEffectView delay with UIModalTransitionStyle CrossDissolve

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swift3

I'm presenting a modal view controller that has a background with a `UIVisualEffectView` with an `UIBlurEffect` of type `.light`

I'm presenting the modal view controller as below:

```
infoViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(infoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm noticing that the blur effect view does not appear until the `crossDissolve` animation has completed.
This is not the case for other transition styles such as `coverVertical`.

This is happening only on iOS 10 with Swift 3.

How can I get the `crossDissolve` animation to work along with the visual effect view on my `infoViewController`. Any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: Your code is working fine with iOS 10 (Swift 3) test project. Are you sure you're not doing any manipulations with view in `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` methods?

Comment: No manipulations at all. For me the cross dissolve animation completes with which the popup view animates to visibility, only after which the background uieffect view suddenly appears.

Comment: Can you wrap it in a test project, so that I can reproduce it and fix?

Comment: ...or provide code for `infoViewController` first

Comment: Same happens to me. No clue why it is happening so far :/.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It works fine on iOS 9, but not iOS 10.

Comment: Here is the answer in Objective C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671408/uivisualeffectview-in-ios-10

Comment: Same problem here, disabling the animation or choosing other transition styles will help with the issue but then I'll lose the smoother feeling.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is replacing the `crossDisolve` with a `CATransition`, like this:

```
self.present(controller,
             animated: false,
             completion: nil)

let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.type = kCATransitionFade
view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What happens to the animation after it's done.? If it's added to the layer, should it be removed again, or could that be ignored?

Comment: It can be ignored. The transition is automatically removed when done

Answer (score 1):

Check your consule, you should see there the reason -

> <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x7fe053562840> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.

You can't use the `UIVisualEffectView` with `crossDissolve` animation...